# momentum-driven scrolling <body> hijacks tap events to overlays?

Tags: ipad, scroll, mobile-safari, overflow

I've been working with overlays that have scrollable content (via `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`) on a web app targeting new-ish iPads.

The designs call for certain scrollable overlays to be occasionally visible over the regular body content, while keeping that body content touchable. These overlays aren't modals, they're more like menus.

Everything's mostly fine and I haven't had to resort to custom scrollers yet (like [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) or [ftscroller](https://github.com/ftlabs/ftscroller)). But I'm experiencing one issue:

If you scroll the main body content (long articles, etc) quickly and let momentum carry the animation, subsequent taps inside the overlay content are treated as taps to the body directly. The result is that the overlays appear frozen, since they can't be interacted with as the body itself is moving. Any actions taken on them is translated to gestures aimed at the body.

I've tried enabling iScroll on the overlay scrollers to no avail, as taps into them are still being hijacked by the body as it scrolls.

Has anyone experienced this and come up with any work arounds?